# GAE queue task does not log errors

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a task in my queue, which fails and gets return. When I look at the task in the task queue via the GAE dashboard / console I can see that the last http response code was    500 (Internal server error) but there is no error message in the logs as to why it failed.

When I run the function outside of the queue, an error message is logged as expected. I have tried running the task on a backend instance and a frontend instance - in neither case is the error logged.

Comment: "When I look at the task" how do you look at the task? Where exactly did you see it return error 500?

Comment: What is the task url that is returning an error, and which admin console url are you using to look at the logs?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for Task Queue to dispatch a task, but for the task to not actually execute on one of your instances.  This typically happens if there aren't any free instances available, and the task goes into the queue for an instance but exceeds the maximum waiting time in the queue.

We plan to add a new header, X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount, which shows the number of times a task has been executed by an instance.  It's probably something that should be displayed on the console too.